# Custom component in Angular 6: values to boolean attributes

Tags: html, angular, typescript, components

I'm developing a web application using Angular 6. I have a question: 
I would like to create some custom components that are inspired by the components of HTML input. However, there are differences in native attributes between attributes that assume values and attributes that can be written / not written, such as:

```
<input type="text" required maxlength="10 />
```

In this case, `maxlength` must receive a data, while `required` has a different typology: it can be there or not!
Here is mine costom component:

**TypeScript**

```
export class CustomComponent {

  @Input() maximumLength: number;

  @Input() isRequired: boolean;
}
```

**Template HTML**

```
<input type="text"
       [attr.maxlength]="maximumLength"
       [required] = "isRequired"
/>
```

`maximumLength` seems to work perfectly, but I have a question about `isRequired`: I don't understand if this is the right way to personalize it... this written attribute (`required`) receives a value (`isRequired`), but in reality there should be or not be according to the value passed to it.
Using the component like that:

```
<custom-component maximumLength="10" isRequired="true"></custom-component>
```

it would seem that the associated HTML (`<input type="text">`) 
does not have the `required` attribute.

Comment: your code is valid, not sure what isn't working. [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r1xx9f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponent-b%2Fcomponent-b.component.html)

Comment: Have you heard about [`ControlValueAccessor`](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/)s ?

Comment: @trichetriche yes, actually my component uses it ..
unfortunately, the attribute does not seem to be present

Comment: @ConnorsFan, it's not true. It doesn't work anyway

Comment: According to [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfjy3x), setting the property with `[isRequired]="myValue"` should work.